# how can i change state in vuex from a component

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

I am starting with vuex and i am little bit confused. I want to show a cart when element is clicked in another component(navbar), and cart component will be shown inside home view. Here is my code:
Navbar

```
<img src="../assets/icons/cart-icon.svg" class="icon" @click="$store.commit('customChange')" />
```

Home

```
<div v-if="showCartHere">
  <Cart />
</div>
<script>
import Cart from '../components/Cart.vue'

export default {
    name: 'Home',
    components: { Cart },
    data() {
        return {
            showCartHere: false
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.showCartHere = this.$store.state.showCart
    }
}
</script>
```

Store

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    showCart: false
  },
  getters: {
    showCart: state => {
      return state.showCart
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    customChange(state) {
      return state.showCart = !state.showCart
    }
  },
  actions: {
    customChange({ commit }) {
      commit('customChange')
    }
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

Comment: When i manally change 'showCart' in store to true, cart become visible, but i am making some mistake with calling a function i guess. Thanks.

Comment: you need to dispatch an action from component to vuex module. Your action will call a mutation and will update the state. 
`this.$store.dispatch('module/ACTION', params)` this will be used to dispatch an action from component.

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/main/examples/classic/shopping-cart you can refer this as this is provided by vuex

Comment: Can you please give more details? do i have to change something more or just this.$store.dispatch('module/ACTION', params) instead of $store.commit('customChange')

Comment: Eventually i made it. What i was missing was calling mapGetters in Home component. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Component

```
<template>
  <p v-if="showcart">Show</p>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
computed: (state) => {
  showCart: state.cart.showCart
}
methods: {
  showCartIcon() {
    this.$store.dispatch('cart/show', true)
  }
}
</script>
```

Now in your module/Cart.js

```
const state = () => ({
  showCart: false,
})
const actions = {
  show({commit}) {
    commit('showcartMt', true)
  }
}

const mutations = {
  showcartMt(state, toggle) {
    state.showCart = toggle;
  }
}
```

Comment: you should call action from component and your action will call mutation which will update the state. Now in your component, a computed property will keep track of changes and it can be used in you template just the way i have shown